# Toggle 2 Divs in the same position with 2 different buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a really newbie question for you guys. I want to make a page which looks like the img below. And this is how I want it to work:  I click one of the two buttons, then change the question/statement to a new one in the exact same place as the one before while the buttons stay the same (without messing up the structure). I tried a few methods from stackoverflow, but I couldn't get it working.

[image]

Thanks for your help!

My code looks like this. What I've got so far:

```
<div class="row" id="pic">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
    <div  align="center">
      <img src="justin2.png"/>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="large-12 columns">
 <div class="question1"><h1 >This is a german shepherd.</h1></div>
 <div class="question2"><h1 >This is rottweiler.</h1></div>
 <div  align="center" >
 <a href="#" id="True" class="button success" >True</a>
 <a href="#" id="False" class="button alert" >False</a></div>
```

Comment: Please show what you tried. Lots of people say the tried...when all the really expect is to have someone else do the work for them. A display of your effort goes a long way in getting help

Comment: Do your questions `div` have static height?

Comment: i think they have i tried previously the class:"panel" and i using zurb foundation so i think its predefined but maybe not.

Comment: i tried a method: myscript.js looks like this
 $('#toggle').click(function() {
    $('#container > .toggleMe').toggle();
    $(this).text(function(i,txt) {
        return txt === "Show viewB" ? "Show viewA" : "Show viewB";
    });
});

and i named the divs like this:

<div id='container'>
    <div id='divA' class='toggleMe'>DIV A</div>
    <div id='divB' class='toggleMe'>DIV B</div>
</div>​
<a href='#' id='toggle'>Show viewB</a>​

and divB in css file display:none

i tried to use this sample but didnt worked.

Comment: What you mean by `without messing up the structure`? could you `slideUp` current active div and `slideDown` the next one? your buttons will shift up for a second. is that acceptable?

Comment: yes, i want them to stay in their position while the statment/question changes. Is that possible? if not i can accept that.

Comment: yes it's possible, could you give your question's div a static min and max height?

Comment: Sure, this will solve my problem? Somehow this script isnt the best though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap all you question between one division with `relative` position and change your question position to absolute.
Because you can have good vision of that, I wrote and implement it in `jsfiddle`.

[You can check the code consist of js, html and css here](https://jsfiddle.net/8cxaev4g/2/)

Comment: Thank you Sir, You made my day!